# Firebase dynamic link(Send some data)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am new in Android development, I am currently work on Firebase dynamic link in my Android app. I have successfully create and send dynamic link but not to able some data with dynamic link so can anyone answer my question. How can I send some data with dynamic link with other user?

Generated dynamic link:
***https://wxpx5.app.goo.gl/?link=https://link.com&apn=com.example.ongraph.deeplinkdemo***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how to pass your data in Firebase Dynamic Link?

You can pass data in deep link.
In your example dynamic link is `https://wxpx5.app.goo.gl/?link=https://link.com&apn=com.example.ongraph.deeplinkdemo` . Here deep link is `https://link.com`.

To pass more data you can add parameters to deep link, for example `https://link.com?parameter1=abcd&parameter2=123&parameter3=<base64 data if needed raw data>`.
After you created deep link with your data, you wrap the link into dynamic link. If you creating links manually you will need to URL-escape the deep link.

Comment: @ Oleksiy Ivanov yes i want to send some extra data with link. Thanks it works for me.